# Estirar imagen SVG para que ocupe todo el tamaño del contenedor

Tags: html, css, svg

Tengo una imagen SVG (en un fichero, aunque para efectos prácticos, podría ser *inline*) y quiero que ocupe todo el espacio del contenedor. Para ello he definido un alto y ancho al `div` que la contiene, y le he puesto en CSS un ancho y alto de 100% a la imagen:

```css
div {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}

div svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="320" height="90" viewBox="0 0 320 90">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="320" height="90" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#114477" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Pero como se puede ver en el ejemplo de arriba, la imagen sólo llega al primer límite que se encuentre (ancho o alto) y, aunque sigue creciendo, no llega a ocupar todo el espacio del contenedor (la imagen no se estira) que es lo que me interesa.

¿Cómo podría conseguir esto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás intentando deformar la imagen, es decir cambiar el aspecto. Si lo que necesitas es ocupar todo el área simplemente debes proporcionar el valor `none` al atributo `preserveAspectRatio` de la marca `svg` para indicar que quieres modificar la proporción:

```
<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Sólo eso necesitas para resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola @JuanManuel. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Excelente respuesta. Estoy seguro que se vería mucho mejor si pudieses agregarle el código completo. Debajo de tu respuesta está el enlace para [edit], y dentro del editor hay que hacer click en el botón "*fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS*"

Answer (score 2):

```css
div#rectangulo {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}

div#rectangulo * {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangulo">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0"  rx="10" ry="10" fill="#114477" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Fíjate en las modificaciones que hice. Tus etiquetas `svg` y `rect` contenían valores width y height por lo que sobreescribían los que habías escrito anteriormente.

El id `rectangulo` para identificar más fácilmente el div al que quieres agregarle esa propiedad

Comment: Esta solución funciona para esta imagen en concreto (que es un ejemplo mínimo), realmente tengo un SVG mucho más complejo (con paths, texto, filtros...) en el que no puedo hacer que todo sea 100% porque no se verá bien. Siento la confusión, debería haber sido más claro.

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque el `width` y `height` del svg no influye en el `width` y `height` de la figura mostrada , el alto y ancho de la figura se manipula mediante el atributo [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox),  como desea que se obtenga dichas propiedades del div(contenedor) , bastaría con no colocar este atributo `viewBox` y añadiéndole `alto` y `ancho` al `rect` de `100%`

```css
    div {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}

 svg {
  width:100% ;
  height:100% ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#114477" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta solución funciona para esta imagen en concreto (que es un ejemplo mínimo), realmente tengo un SVG mucho más complejo (con paths, texto, filtros...) en el que no puedo hacer que todo sea 100% porque no se verá bien. Siento la confusión, debería haber sido más claro.